# Javascript "MULTIPLE Selection" Select box validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, drop-down-menu

I Have a Multiple selection select box. I need it to be validated using javascript, so that it should prompt to select atleast one value.

Below is the multiple select box I Have.

```
<select name="usrgrp[]" multiple="multiple" size="3">
<option value="11">abc</option>
<option value="12">def</option>
<option value="13">ghi</option>
</select>
```

Please help me to write the validation javascript for this select box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (referenceToForm.elements["usrgrp[]"].selectedIndex == -1) {
  alert("Please select an item.");
}
```

Comment: what if the 0th selection is `<option value="">--Please Select--</option>`

Comment: @RaheelHasan Just change the index you are testing against to exclude it:  `.selectedIndex > 0`

Comment: if a person selects `0th` (which is "please select"), `1st` and `5th` and so on... try and run your code and it will still fail at 0th. Even though the user has selected other options as well..

Comment: @RaheelHasan Oops, I complete overlooked that it's a `multiple`. In that case loop over `options` and check is one (other that the 0th) is `selected`.

Comment: OTOH, I just realized that a "please select" entry doesn't make sense on a multiple select.

Comment: ok lets do this way: huge form, users selected multiple from this select box, then realize its optional to how will he unselect without refreshing the page? The only way is to select "Please Select"

Comment: @RaheelHasan It depends on how the browser (or OS) implements the select, but usually by Ctrl-clicking the selected item. Since that is not obvious, it's usually better to use checkboxes instead.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is use ! :

```
   if (!$('select').val())
    {
         //fail       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the [Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) docs. If you find the need to validate more than just that field (perhaps you're building a form?), then using the Validation pluggin will help you much more than hacking together individual rules.

Give it a shot, it's well written and contains many examples.